# Spyder Kernel crashes when using tesserocr

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, tesseract, spyder

I first installed `tesserocr` on Windows 10 and Anaconda3 (Python 3.7.0) via

`conda install -c simonflueckiger/label/tesseract-4.0.0-master tesserocr`

then I wanted to downgrade to `tesseract 3.x` and did

`conda uninstall tesserocr`

After this; I tried to install `tesserocr` again via:

`conda install -c simonflueckiger tesserocr`

But now my kernel in Spyder keeps crashing when I run the following:

```
import tesserocr
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('test.png')

s = tesserocr.image_to_text(im, path='C:/path/to/tessdata')
```

If I remove the `path`-argument, i get: `RuntimeError: Failed to init API`

Can anyone help to fix this?